How can a D-lock be bent inward by a thief?
A low value* - but very useful - bike of mine was stolen the other day.  The D lock (Kryptolok Series 2) I'd put through both seat stays and the back wheel was squeezed.  Locking this way means there's too much bike in the way to get a bottle jack in there and jack it outwards. The lock mechanism still works, but stiffly, and the bolt is chewed up at the end where it meets the shackle. Walking through the city centre (which I wouldn't normally do) I've seen a few other shackles bent in the same way.  Seemingly most of them are the same model with a hook at one end, but I have spotted at least one that locked at both ends.

Note that's it's on top of an abandoned motorbike chain, and the gap between the 2 ends is enough to get round seatstays, but not the hoop it's locked to.
How can a thief apply enough force to bend a 12mm steel shackle inwards like this?  I want to know to try and mitigate the risks in the future (although I may replace it with a folding bike I can take on the train; I'll still need to be able to lock that up sometimes).  A much smaller shackle (mini D) wouldn't go round some of the hoops I lock it to.

*  I paid £60 for the frame, added about the same value in dynamo lighting and a few other parts from my stash of spares

No witness marks from tools on the lock body, but where the end of the shackle hooks into it the metal is cracked and the plastic cover is dislodged. If I get a picture I'll update the question

You could achieve this by putting a loop of metal cable (eg a short bike lock or wrapped twice) then, as suggested in the answers, use a lever eg breaker bar to tighten the loop and crush your lock. I think it wouldn't take much effort or really much time either.

Low value or not, I understand your pain.  Particularly if it meant being stranded away from home without transport.  My sympathies.

Thanks @TobySpeight. Luckily I wasn't stranded, just left with tricky logistics for a while

It might be worth asking this on diy.SE with a focus on "what tool could do this?"

I do not know whether it is true but I have heard bikes are used as a lever to twist the lock they are locked with.

@Willeke probably not in this case though I wouldn't rule out out for a heavy steel frame. This was an aluminium frame and seatstays are always among the lightest tubes. They'd buckle before the lock would do anything

My best guess would be:
Wrap a dyneema soft shackle around the D-lock. Use a metal lever to twist soft shackle which will in turn apply inwards pressure on your D-lock.

You can get a lot of mechanical advantage that way. Also explains no marks on the Lock shackle.
My guess is as good as anyone's.
Sorry to hear your bike got stolen. I hope it does not put you off riding.

I'm pretty certain this has to be it.  Even tough webbing might be enough if used in a way that doesn't stress the edges. I'd test but I wouldn't waste a functioning  lock especially as I'm down one anyway

Power of the lever. A long pry bar though the lock and twist. Pole provides counter resistance. Bike frame and other bits in the middle of the lock either moves out the way or gets damaged.




That specific approach still applies an outward force and leaves the shackle wider than it started, so I don't think that's quite it., but close. To collapse the shackle would definitely need to lever against something and would probably cause such obvious damage to the bike they end up with nothing worth selling. But it's interesting that they managed to you it with a fairly light piece of steel channel that was clearly only just strong enough

'Custom' tool that slips over the lock section, long lever to rotate it would create no outward force, just twisting action.

I've got the lock body at home (considering it my litter) so I can look for witness marks.  Don't recall any though

@chrish https://www.tinkercad.com/things/imv4MHvgc5B-chrish-d-lock-braker something like that might have enough leverage, if the pole were long enough.  Or some kind of screw thread might do it, a big G clamp with some tangs to hold onto the D lock sides while compressing

@Criggie your design looks plausible, perhaps made out of pipe, with a socket for a longer lever; I wonder if they've been spotted in the wild.  It's a shame I couldn't retrieve the shackle because I'd like to test some of the forces involved and do my own destructive testing (I still may try smashing the lock body after freezing it in liquid nitrogen).  I think I've seen G clamps with V-groove jaws, but can't find them online.  Easy enough to customise if you've got an angle grinder at home, as any bike thief would.

I'm thinking clamp or a wench of some sort.  I can't imagine someone lugging a vise around that is big enough but that might work too.  Something along those lines.

A long time ago I had something called 'bones' (maybe) that slid onto the D-bar to reinforce it against leverage attacks. I stopped using them because they were a pain but maybe something like that could prevent this.

Uh I mean 'winch' like this: https://www.grainger.com/category/material-handling/lifting-pulling-positioning/winches/manual-winches
